# Addition of values inside an Array according to certain value

Tags: javascript, arrays, sum

I have an array like this:

```
let array = [[0, 1, 4.75], [0, 1, 2.12], [0, 3, 8.1]];
```

Expected output:

```
let expectedOutput = [[0, 1, 6.87], [0, 3, 8.1]];
```

In this case `4.75 + 2.12` has been summed up because first two values were matching `[0, 1]`.

I want to lookup the first and second value in the sub-array und sum the third value of all the sub-arrays that has the same first and second value. Can you please help me out?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Lots of things.... because the data consists of huge arrays, none of my tries gave me the result I need and they were very slow... and I do not have the full JS knowledge... :(

Comment: How exactly do you want this to happen? check for all arrays inside the outer array and sum it up? check for 1&2, 3&4, 5&6 etc? check for 1&2, 2&3, 3&4? please be more specific and also provide examples of what you've tried.

Comment: _"none of my tries gave me the result I need and they were very slow..."_ - the criterion "speed" is pretty irrelevant, as long as the results do not even match what you need. And for developing _any_ that approach that first of all gets the desired result, the "huge" arrays should not play a role yet either - you can make an attempt to come up with something that works for your rather tiny example data sets you have given here first of all. If it needs improvements in terms of speed, we can still focus on that later.

Comment: I want to lookup the first and second value in the sub-array und sum the third value of all the sub-arrays that has the same first and second value.

Comment: So you'd need to check if your new result array already has a matching sub-array - if not, you need to create it at this point and store the current 3rd value into it, otherwise add the current 3rd value to what is already in there. To make it so that you do not have to loop over your new array all the time and check the items for equality in two values, you can use a helper _object_ first, and combine the two values into one "key" value, for example in form of JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When building the result, check if the current element matches a previous one, and then either add only the value or the whole element:

```js
let array = [[0, 1, 4.75], [0, 1, 2.12], [0, 3, 8.1]];

const result = array.reduce( (r, [x,y,v], i) => (i = r.find(e => e[0] === x && e[1] === y), i ? i[2] += v : r.push([x,y,v]), r), [])

console.log(result)
```

Comment: I like 1-liner solutions as much as the next js dev, but a little more readability and explanation sure wouldn't hurt.

Comment: @Plagiatus Yes, I would not use code like this in a code base, and I would not recommend handing it in for a homework assignment (which is why I think that kind of code is so popular on SO - apart from being the most fun kind of course). In general, it is (and should be) only the POC to the actual answer.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const array = [
  [0, 1, 4.75],
  [0, 1, 2.12],
  [0, 3, 8.1]
];

// groups arrays by first and second item
const groups = {}

for (const [a1, a2, a3] of array) {
  if (!(a1 in groups)) {
    groups[a1] = {}
  }
  if (!(a2 in groups[a1])) {
    groups[a1][a2] = []
  }
  groups[a1][a2].push(a3)
}

// sum the third item

const result = []

for (const a1 in groups) {
  for (const a2 in groups[a1]) {
    const sum = groups[a1][a2].reduce((s, c) => s + c, 0)
    result.push([+a1, +a2, sum])
  }
}

console.log(result)
```